# how to return values selected by hibernate query in json form?

Tags: java

my question here is how do i return values selected from hibernate query in the json form.

**BankController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getohlcall", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Trading_Data> getOhlcAll(@RequestBody OhlcRequest ohlcRequest) {
    List<Trading_Data> list;
    list = bankServices.getOhlc(ohlcRequest);
    return list;
}
```

My DAO implementation class which for now returns four values.

**BankDaoImpl.java**

```
public List<Trading_Data> getOhlc(OhlcRequest ohlcRequest){
    sessionFactory.openSession();
    session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Trading_Data.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("minPrice"), "minPrice")
                    .add(Projections.property("maxPrice"), "maxPrice")
                    .add(Projections.property("closingPrice"), "closingPrice")
                    .add(Projections.property("prevClosing"), "prevClosing"))
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Trading_Data.class));

    List<Trading_Data> list = cr.list();
    return list;

}
```

My entity class which is mapped with my table in database.

**Trading_Data.java**

```
public class Trading_Data  {
@Entity
@Table
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Trading_Data  {

@Id
@Column
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
private String stockCode;

@Column
private long maxPrice;

@Column
private long minPrice;

@Column
private long closingPrice;

@Column
private long prevClosing;

@Column
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
private String eDate;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getStockCode() {
    return stockCode;
}

public void setStockCode(String stockCode) {
    this.stockCode = stockCode;
}

public long getMaxPrice() {
    return maxPrice;
}

public void setMaxPrice(long maxPrice) {
    this.maxPrice = maxPrice;
}

public long getMinPrice() {
    return minPrice;
}

public void setMinPrice(long minPrice) {
    this.minPrice = minPrice;
}

public long getClosingPrice() {
    return closingPrice;
}

public void setClosingPrice(long closingPrice) {
    this.closingPrice = closingPrice;
}

public long getPrevClosing() {
    return prevClosing;
}

public void setPrevClosing(long prevClosing) {
    this.prevClosing = prevClosing;
}

public String geteDate() {
    return eDate;
}

public void seteDate(String eDate) {
    this.eDate = eDate;
}
}
```

Json data i am currently getting is

```
[
{
"id": 0,
"maxPrice": 54,
"minPrice": 58,
"closingPrice": 45,
"prevClosing": 215
}
]
```

as you can see i don't want id for this api but i might want for some other api.

My questions are:-

1. is there no way for eg. returning only those values(in json format) which are selected by hibernate query ?
2. for e.g i created one pojo class which has four properties (maxprice, minprice, prevclosing,closingprice). can i map this pojo class with values returned by hibernate query and return to the client in json format?

Comment: You have lot of options, what I use for this is gson. I return my entity object, then I transform it to a bussiness object, and then I use gson.toJson(object) to send as json

Comment: do you have any working example?

Comment: you need to add Gson as dependency and then in the return of your controller you need to gson.toJson(list);

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'produces' in your resource method. Like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getohlcall", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<Trading_Data> getOhlcAll(@RequestBody OhlcRequest ohlcRequest) {
    List<Trading_Data> list;
    list = bankServices.getOhlc(ohlcRequest);
    return list;
}
```